# Flutter Web GetConnect response 400 bad request on the patch request

Tags: flutter, http, patch, flutter-getx

I tried to make a request to my server using the GetConnect's patch method and received a 400 Bad Request response.
However, when I used Insomnia to test the same URL, body, and token, everything worked fine.
I also noticed that my server didn't receive the request sent by the Flutter web application.
here's my code:

```
 Future<Map> editRecordTitleByRecordId({
    required String recordId,
    required String newTitle,
  }) async {
    String route = '${uri}record/edit_title?record_id=$recordId';
    Map result = {};
    var header = {"Authorization": "bearer $accessToken"};
    var body = {"title": newTitle};
    var contentType = "application/json";

    try {
      var response =
          await patch(route, body, headers: header, contentType: contentType);

      result['status'] = true;
      result['content'] = response.body;
    } catch (e) {
      result = responseErrorHandle(e);
    }
    return result;
  }
```